# XML to XML transformation with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to transform an XML file to another XML file. Here is my input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="inlamning.xsl"?>
<Ansokan>

  <forskola_namn>Kopparholmen</forskola_namn>

  <barn persunnummer="200505051111">
    <namn>Niklas Niklasson</namn>
    <syskon_pnr>200606061111</syskon_pnr>
    <allergi>Laktos</allergi>
  </barn>

  <vardnadshavare personnummer="198606061111">
    <fornamn>Magnus</fornamn>
    <efternamn>Niklasson</efternamn>
    <adress>
      <hem>Magnusgatan 10</hem>
      <jobb>Jobbgatan 1</jobb>
    </adress>
    <telefon>
      <hem>0520-12345</hem>
      <mobil>077-731731</mobil>
    </telefon>
  </vardnadshavare>

  <vardnadshavare personnummer="198605051111">
    <fornamn>Hanna</fornamn>
    <efternamn>Niklasson</efternamn>
    <adress>
      <hem>Magnusgatan 10</hem>
      <jobb>Jobbgatan 5</jobb>
    </adress>
    <telefon>
      <hem></hem>
      <mobil>077-721721</mobil>
    </telefon>
  </vardnadshavare>

  <annat_ommande_skal>Inget</annat_ommande_skal>

</Ansokan>
```

And this is the transformated XML I try to do:

```
<begaranominkomstuppgift>
   <person personnummer="">
      <fornamn></fornamn>
      <efternamn></efternamn>
   </person>
   <person personnummer="">
      <fornamn></fornamn>
      <efternamn></efternamn>
   </person>
</begaranominkomstuppgift>
```

What I'm trying to do is, creating a new root as `<begaranominkomstuppgift>` and taking 2 vardnadshavare as `<person>` with the attribute, and taking just vardnadshavare `<fornamn>` and `<efternamn>`.

And this is my XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" />

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <begaranominkomstuppgift>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Ansokan/vardnadshavare" />
            </begaranominkomstuppgift>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="Ansokan/vardnadshavare">
            <xsl:element name="person" personnummer="{@personnummer}">
                <xsl:element name="fornamn">
                    <xsl:value‐of select="fornamn" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="efternamn">
                    <xsl:value‐of select="efternamn" />
                </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSL file is probably not taking the right information. And moreover after transformation I can't see the tags. I mean even if I choose the right information, it's not showing xml tags after the transformation. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You might want to choose a more specific title for your post. "XML to XML transformation with XSL" is about as generic as it gets, and it describes almost every XSLT question on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* what you would like to do is the following. The most significant differences between your solution and mine:

- if you know what the name of an element is going to be, there is no need for `<xsl:element name="person">`, simply use `<person>`
- inside the new `person`, I use `copy-of` to copy the two elements

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Ansokan">
        <begaranominkomstuppgift>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </begaranominkomstuppgift>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="vardnadshavare">
        <person personnummer="{@personnummer}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="fornamn | efternamn"/>
        </person>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<begaranominkomstuppgift>
   <person personnummer="198606061111">
      <fornamn>Magnus</fornamn>
      <efternamn>Niklasson</efternamn>
   </person>
   <person personnummer="198605051111">
      <fornamn>Hanna</fornamn>
      <efternamn>Niklasson</efternamn>
   </person>
</begaranominkomstuppgift>
```

Try this solution online [here](http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGcC).

---

> XSL file is probably not taking the right information. And moreover after transformation I cant see the tags. I mean even if I choose the right information, its not showing xml tags after the transformation. Where am I doing wrong?

The problems with your original XSLT code are that 1) one of the `xsl:element` instructions is not closed and 2) `personnummer` cannot be an attribute of `xsl:element`. You would have to use `xsl:attribute`:

```
<xsl:element name="person">
  <xsl:attribute name="personnummer" select="@personnummer"/>
```

Also, the hyphen characters you have used between `value` and `of` are somehow not recognized by my processor.

But usually, if a transformation is "not showing tags" it's because of a *namespace*. Chances are that your input document has a *default namespace* that you have not shown to us.