# Why does this XSLT not generate my expected output?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform an XML to another XML, using XSLT.
Here's my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "iso-8859-1"?>
<Förskoleansökan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLTFile1.xslt"?>

  <Förskolenamn>Dalabergs förskola</Förskolenamn>

  <Barn>

    <Förnamn>Nils</Förnamn>
    <Efternamn>Petersson</Efternamn>
    <Personnummer>1008021245</Personnummer>


    <Syskon>
      <Personnummer>0005052464</Personnummer>
      <Förnamn>Johan</Förnamn>
      <Efternamn>Petersson</Efternamn>

    </Syskon>

    <Övrigt>

      <Allergier>Inga allergier</Allergier>
      <AnnatÖmmandeSkäl></AnnatÖmmandeSkäl>


    </Övrigt>

  </Barn>

  <Vårdnadshavare>

     <Vårdnadshavare1 personnummer="7806032356">
            <Förnamn>Mia</Förnamn>
            <Efternamn>Petersson</Efternamn>
    </Vårdnadshavare1>

    <Vårdnadshavare2 personnummer="7806089645">
            <Förnamn>Jörgen</Förnamn>
            <Efternamn>Petersson</Efternamn>
       
    </Vårdnadshavare2>

  </Vårdnadshavare>


</Förskoleansökan>
```

I'm trying to transform that XML to this one

```
<begaranominkomstuppgift>
    <person personnummer="7806032356">
      <fornamn>Mia</fornamn>
      <efternamn>Petersson</efternamn>
    </person>
    <person personnummer="7806089645">
      <fornamn>Jörgen</fornamn>
      <efternamn>Petersson</efternamn>
    </person>
</begaranominkomstuppgift>
```

Here's my XSL

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <begaraninkomstuppgift>
      <xsl:for-each select="Förskoleansökan/Vårdnadshavare">
        <person>
          <xsl:attribute name="personummer">
            <xsl:value-of select="personnummer"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <fornamn>
            <xsl:value-of select="Vårdnadshavare/Förnamn" />
          </fornamn>
          <efternamn>
            <xsl:value-of select="Vårdnadshavare/Efternamn" />
          </efternamn>
        </person>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </begaraninkomstuppgift>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The transformation doesn't occur and my output is still the old XML. What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: Would you mind explaining why [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34711656/1987598) has asked something _very_ similar?

Comment: Maybe that's a classmate of mine? I'm positive he/she is. Can you help me though?

Comment: Have a look at my [answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34711794/1987598) first and see if it makes sense to you. Also, be careful when asking for solutions for homework assignments. XSLT programmers (I guess your teacher is one) notice immediately if a stylesheet was written by a beginner or an expert on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I did read his question and answers but they're not really helping me with my issue. As far as i can see, i have no errors on my XML and i can't figure out what the problem is. On your second point, yes i acknowledge that.

Comment: Your input XML document has some bad design flaws. Since I assume that putting together the XML input is part of your assignment, first rethink the XML document structure. Afterwards, it will be easier to write an XSLT stylesheet to process it. If this is indeed desgined by yourself, I'll add an answer explaining this if you like.

Comment: The XML is most certainly my work and basically i'm happy about the structure. I structured the way it's easiest for me. I would greatly appreciate it, if you could help me out here. I'm not expecting you to create a completely new stylesheet, but just point out the flaws in my current one.

Comment: You might have structured the XML in a way that seems easiest to you, that does not make it a good way to structure an XML document. I second Mathias, this input document is a horrible (I'd even say bordering-on-insane) way to structure XML document, before you do anything else, restructure it. It's a waste of time to even think about XSLT for this XML (on your end and on ours).

Comment: Well i'm a beginner so that's why it looks really bad to you guys. The important thing is that the XML is well-formed and does not contain any errors. But can you kinda explain what the issue here is regarding the XSL? Why does it not transform? It seems like i used the correct select-expressions on my XSL but it won't do anything.

Comment: "*The transformation doesn't occur and my output is still the old XML*" No, that's not what happens - see: http://xsltransform.net/94rmq6z

Comment: @michael.hor257k You're right, i checked with a browser and got a little confused. But why is it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is it not working?

It **is** working - it's just not working the way you expect.

The main reason for this is that you create a person for each `Förskoleansökan/Vårdnadshavare`. There is only one `Vårdnadshavare` element in your XML, so only one person is created.

To get the two persons you want, you need to create a person for each child node of `Vårdnadshavare`. You have named these `Vårdnadshavare1` and `Vårdnadshavare2`, which makes it difficult to select them by name. If we assume that they are the **only** children of `Vårdnadshavare`, we could do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Förskoleansökan/Vårdnadshavare/*">
    <person>
    ...
```

Your next mistake is that you use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="personnummer"/>
```

instead of:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="@personnummer"/>
```

Finally, `Förnamn` and `Efternamn` are direct children of `Vårdnadshavare1`/`Vårdnadshavare2` - so an expression like `Vårdnadshavare/Förnamn` does not select anything.

Try this corrected stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <begaraninkomstuppgift>
      <xsl:for-each select="Förskoleansökan/Vårdnadshavare/*">
        <person>
          <xsl:attribute name="personummer">
            <xsl:value-of select="@personnummer"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <fornamn>
            <xsl:value-of select="Förnamn" />
          </fornamn>
          <efternamn>
            <xsl:value-of select="Efternamn" />
          </efternamn>
        </person>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </begaraninkomstuppgift>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "The main reason for this is that you create a person for each Förskoleansökan/Vårdnadshavare. There is only one Vårdnadshavare element in your XML, so only one person is created." I figured this had something to do with it. And of course i forgot the right way to select an attribute(@). Thanks for explaining it clearly!

Answer (score 2):

> The XML is most certainly my work and basically i'm happy about the structure. I structured the way it's easiest for me. I would greatly appreciate it, if you could help me out here. I'm not expecting you to create a completely new stylesheet, but just point out the flaws in my current one.

The primary goal of Stackoverflow is to teach people what they need to know, not to give them what they want.

An XSLT transformation never exists on its own (exception: generic transformations like the identity transform), it only makes sense if it is related to a specific input XML document. The input is what you start with.

Sometimes, you will find yourself in a situation where the input is defined by someone else (your customer, an external provider, your boss wants it this way etc.) and you have to cope with it, no matter if the XML format is sensible or not.

But that's not the case for you, you are in charge of designing your own input document and choosing a good design will greatly simplify the task of creating an XSLT stylesheet to process the input (your ultimate goal).

> Well i'm a beginner so that's why it looks really bad to you guys. The important thing is that the XML is well-formed and does not contain any errors.

No, not really. Well-formedness is a *precondition* for anything to be called XML in the first place, but it does not say anything about the usefulness of the design.

---

Now let's have a look at your design. First of all, the `<?xml-stylesheet` processing instruction should be at the beginning of the file, right after the XML declaration:

Next, looking at the contents of `Barn`:

```
<Barn>
    <Förnamn>Nils</Förnamn>
    <Efternamn>Petersson</Efternamn>
    <Personnummer>1008021245</Personnummer>
    <Syskon>
        <Personnummer>0005052464</Personnummer>
        <Förnamn>Johan</Förnamn>
        <Efternamn>Petersson</Efternamn>
    </Syskon>
    <Övrigt>
        <Allergier>Inga allergier</Allergier>
        <AnnatÖmmandeSkäl/>
    </Övrigt>
</Barn>
```

The three same elements occur as direct children of `Barn` and also inside `Syskon`, but the order is different, which does not make sense. The order of elements is significant in XML.

Above, the person number is represented as an element, but later in the document, the person number is stored as an attribute, which will certainly cause confusion.

Inside `Vårdnadshavare`, there are the child elements `Vårdnadshavare1` and `Vårdnadshavare2`. Element names should never be designed in this way because it complicates automatic processing (because each element name is unique) and because the number is actually the *position* of the element, which is obvious.

Things that are the same should have the same name, without a number. If you need the number in it, you could have an attribute like

```
<Vårdnadshavare n="1">
```

but, as I said, it is almost certainly superfluous.

**Please note**: On many aspects of the design I cannot comment because the element names are in a language I do not understand. And it is hard to propose an improved XML design because of this. If you plan to ask further XSLT questions, you might get better help if you translate the content.

Comment: I will certainly follow your tips next time i create a new XML document. But at the moment, why isn't the output of the XSLT as i want it? What seems to be the problem? Can you kind of give some clues as to why? Adjusting my XML isn't really going to solve the issue with the XSL, i feel.

Comment: @Rengaw You should heed this advice for the _current_ XML document. There is no point in explaining to you why the XSLT stylesheet does not transform to the right output, because the XML input is badly designed - as I have tried to explain to you a few times already.